# Enable clean URL in Yii2

Tags: yii2, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

How can I enable clean urls in Yii2. I want to remove index.php and '?' from url parameters. Which section needs to be edited in Yii2 for that?

Comment: I recommedn to use Yii advanced improved for Yii2 projects as many of such issues are already resolved in it and it has many other things already done by the source providers. Just a suggestion

Comment: Take a look in here buddy https://github.com/kevingatp/Yii2-Pretty-URL

Comment: It is basically all about mod_rewrite, well described in the Yii2 docs itself.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I got it working in yii2. Enable `mod_rewrite` for `Apache`.
For `basic template` do the following:
Create a .htaccess file in web folder and add this

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then inside config  folder, in web.php add to components

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
],
```

In the case of `advanced template` create the `.htaccess` files inside `backend/web` and `frontend/web` folders and add `urlManager` component inside `common/config/main.php`

Comment: The rules you applied helped me, I tried without rules but always got error.

Comment: Ok, it seems this one is better. Just remember, that .htaccess file thing is only applicable if you are using apache - it's different with nginx and other web servers. I am deleting the second (mine) answer.

Comment: Sometimes controllers and actions have a dash `-` character.  I had to change `\w+` to `[\w\-]+` to get it to work with those.

Comment: Thank you for adding the answer for an advanced template

Comment: @YasinPatel You are right it's not working for advanced template. Suggest any other solution for advanced template.

Comment: To install mod_rewrite:sudo a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 17):

#### First important point is that

Module_Rewrite is enabled on your server(LAMP,WAMP,XAMP..etc)
For do URL rewiring in yii2 framework Create one .htaccess file and put in /web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

#### Second step

Config folder `common/config/main-local.php` add to components array

```
'urlManager' => [
   'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
   // Disable index.php
   'showScriptName' => false,
   // Disable r= routes
   'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
   'rules' => array(
      '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
      '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
   ),
],
```

Comment: When you have hyphens/dashes in the controller and action names you need to replace `\w+` with `[\w\-]+`.

Answer (score 15):

First, create a `.htaccess` at root folder in your Yii2 project with following content:

```
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

Create another `.htaccess` file in your web folders with following content:

*`frontend/web/`* add *`backend/web/`*
Don't forget to add `.htaccess` file to both web folders:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

---

Now It's done. Change your URL configuration in Yii2:

```
<?php

use \yii\web\Request;
$baseUrl = str_replace('/frontend/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());


$config = [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'aiJXeUjj8XjKYIG1gurMMnccRWHvURMq',
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
        ],
         "urlManager" => [
            'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            "rules" => [
                "home" => "site/index",
                "about-us" => "site/about",
                "contact-us" => "site/contact",
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

return $config;
```

---

Your URL will change to:

`localhost/yii2project/site/about` => `localhost/yii2project/about-us` 
`localhost/yii2project/site/contact` => `localhost/yii2project/contact-us` 
`localhost/yii2project/site/index` => `localhost/yii2project/home`

You can access your admin through

`localhost/yii2project/backend/web`

Comment: After these confuguration in server also we need to enable mod_rewrite.

In terminal run these commands

`sudo a2enmod rewrite` , 
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Now go to “/etc/apache2/apache2.conf” open it your favorite editor and change "**AllowOverride none**" to "**AllowOverride All**" save your changes and you need to restart Apache again by above command.
File will be on readonly mode. So ensure the root login so add "su" command first

`su` , 
`vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`,
`sudo service apache2 restart`
http://tutsnare.com/remove-index-php-from-url-in-yii2/

Answer (score 14):

For me, the problem was:

1. Missing .htaccess in the web folder just like mentioned above.
2. The AllowOverride directive was set to None, which disabled URL rewrites. I changed it to All and now pretty URLs work nicely.

```bash
<Directory "/path/to/the/web/directory/">
  Options Indexes 
  FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
  AllowOverride All 
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: `FollowSymLinks MultiViews ` this line made syntax error in the config file for me and I had to make it like this `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

Answer (score 3):

on nginx configure like that

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: If i did change in default.conf and then browse the url "http://IP/backend/web/site/login" then it show me the page "http://IP" but not my backend login, any idea?

Comment: just did two locations to advanced yii2 app. Separate backend from frontend. And do for backend "root IP/backend/web;" and for frontend "root IP/frontend/web;" in your default.conf file

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to this discussion - I've just installed Yii2, and it includes the following commented-out code in config/web.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'rules' => [],
],
```

If you add the .htaccess file in the accepted answer, then just uncomment the above, pretty URLs will work (I have no idea what the "rules" in the accepted answer are for, but everything seems to work without them).

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** Put `.htaccess` file in root.

```
Options –Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

# Deny accessing below extensions
<Files ~ "(.json|.lock|.git)">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

**Step 2:** Put `.htaccess` file in `frontend/web`.

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Step 3:** Then changes in `frontend/config/main.php`. Following code need to be added inside `'components' => []`.

```
'request' => [
 'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
 'baseUrl' => '/yii-advanced', //http://localhost/yii-advanced
],

'urlManager' => [
  'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
  'showScriptName' => false, // Disable index.php
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // Disable r= routes
  'rules' => array(
          'about' => 'site/about',
          'service' => 'site/service',
          'contact' => 'site/contact',
          'signup' => 'site/signup',
          'login' => 'site/login',
  ),
],
```

Above steps are worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me-
create a .htaccess at root folder of my Yii2 project, and added following-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Created new .htaccess file web folders with following content:

```
frontend/web/
```

and added following-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then added urlmanager here-

```
projectFolder/common/config/main.php
```

For me it was not there, so added this as-

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
   /* 'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

    ],*/
],
```

Make sure this code must be in `'components' => []`.

Restart my server and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Step-by-step instruction**

### Step 1

### At the root of the project add a .htaccess with the following content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

**Step 2**

### In the folder /web add a .htaccess file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

**Step 3**

### In the file /config/web.php in element components of array add folowing code:

```
'request' => [
    // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
    'cookieValidationKey' => 'yYy4YYYX8lYyYyQOl8vOcO6ROo7i8twO',
    'baseUrl' => ''
],

//...

'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '' => 'site/index',                                
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```

Done..

Answer (score 0):

Step1: in project config/main.php eg: frontend/config/main.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [],
        ]
```

Step2: create .htaccess file inset web folder eg: frontend/web

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

#php_flag  display_errors        on
#php_value error_reporting       2039
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code to your config file.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        // your rules go here
    ],
    // ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed yii2 application theme 
go to basic/web/
inside -> .htaccess "paste code below if not exist"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

then go to config/
inside web.php **uncomment** line starting from 47 to 52 (lines may be changed) or something similar to this..

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new version of this framework.

In `backend/config/main.php`, you can see the code that is commented you can use this and do this for the `frontend` folder`.

Answer (score -3):

**config/web.php**

```
$params = require __DIR__ . '/params.php';
$db = require __DIR__ . '/db.php';


$config = [
'id' => 'basic',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'aliases' => [
'@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
'@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
],
'components' => [
'assetManager' => [
// override bundles to use local project files :
'bundles' => [
'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset' => [
'sourcePath' => '@app/assets/source/bootstrap/dist',
'css' => [
YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/bootstrap.css' : 'css/bootstrap.min.css',
],
],
'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
'sourcePath' => '@app/assets/source/bootstrap/dist',
'js' => [
YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/bootstrap.js' : 'js/bootstrap.min.js',
]
],
],
],

'request' => [
// !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
'cookieValidationKey' => 'V_Pj-uMLTPPxv0Be5Bwe3-UCC6EjGRuH',
'baseUrl' => '',
],

'formatter' => [
'dateFormat' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
'decimalSeparator' => ',',
'thousandSeparator' => '.',
'currencyCode'      => 'BRL',
'locale'        => 'pt-BR',
'defaultTimeZone'   => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
'class'         => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
],
'datehelper' => [
'class' => 'app\components\DateBRHelper',
],
'formatcurrency' => [
'class' => 'app\components\FormatCurrency',
],
'request' => [
// !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
'cookieValidationKey' => '123456',

],
'cache' => [
'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
],
'user' => [
'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
'errorHandler' => [
'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
'mailer' => [
'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
// send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
// 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
// for the mailer to send real emails.
'useFileTransport' => true,
],
'log' => [
'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
'targets' => [
[
'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
],
],
],
'db' => $db,

'urlManager' => [
'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
'showScriptName' => false,
'enableStrictParsing' => true,
'rules' => [
'' => 'site/index',                                
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
],
],

],
'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
// uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
//'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
// uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
//'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
];
}

return $config;
```

**arquivo .htaccess na pasta raiz**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess dentro da pasta `web/`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing on StackOverflow. Please use English here.