# upload yii2 websit in cpanel or anyhosting

Tags: cpanel, directadmin, yii2-basic-app

I download yii2_base and editing to my websit

Now, I upload mywebsit in directadmin
but when [redirect my website](http://www.designtk.ir) all of folder `yii2_base` are `show/`

when enter web folder under errors is show:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/u697586846/public_html/web/index.php on line 12
```

I need help for:

1. How to delete folder web from url? `domain.ir/web/.. >> domain.ir`
2. How can I change my url
   `http://localhost/yii_mzh/web/index.php?r=news/shownews&id=5` to under
           url: `http://localhost/yii_mzh/web/index.php?r=news/shownews/id/5`

Answer (score 0):

Removing 'web' folder can be done by using proper .htaccess file if Aapche web server or nginx.conf web server if Nginx webserver (More info on config: [Yii2 htaccess file](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47615-yii-20-basci-app-i-miss-the-htaccess-file/))

Yii2 URL reconfiguring has been asked before and has been answered here [Yii2 pretty URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2)

Comment: tnx. i use apachi webserver. whta code insert htaccess file for delet web folder?

Comment: i cant get you user and password my hosting >> you cant chek my project in webserver?

Comment: It is not advisable to give access of your server to a third party unless you know that person and his/her intentions!

Comment: I am trying to upload my `yii2 application` but unable to do it. I have added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66988294/6854117) can you please see it ?