# YII2 Restfull strange behaviour

Tags: php, rest, get, yii2, restful-architecture

Trying to create API app (based on RESTFull services) using Yii2 Advanced template. Created subdomain api.domain.com for this purpose.

The directory structure looks like this:

[image]

The problem is, when I try to send GET request to `api.domain.com/users` getting following response:

```
{
  "name": "Not Found",
  "message": "Page not found.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 404,
  "type": "yii\web\NotFoundHttpException",
  "previous": {
    "name": "Invalid Route",
    "message": "Unable to resolve the request \"user/index\".",
    "code": 0,
    "type": "yii\base\InvalidRouteException"
  }
}
```

Here is config file:

https://gist.github.com/d1930b6bf20e3d50fe63

Here is controller (which is located in Controllers folder):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/180a7e791e879570e0f4

## The question is...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about your .htaccess file ? did you set extra server configs for clean urls support ?

Comment: @SalemOuerdani nginx file already configured. And it's in right route.

Comment: not sure what is wrong but can you try to remove `components[response]` and the `\yii\web\Request` class from `components[request]` and try if it works ? you may check [this file](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/blob/master/backend/config/api.php), my API works fine within those configs.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani response is ok. The error is not related to response

Comment: Try with this url call `api.domain.com/index.php?r=users`, it works?
In the .htacces you can hide the `index.php` part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that, you added `api` application's path into `bootstrap.php` in common folder. It must look like:

```
<?php
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
Yii::setAlias('api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');                    <-- this line
```

BTW, File located in `common/config/bootstrap.php`

Comment: This fixed it for me, but my bootstrap.php was slightly different

Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(\_\_DIR\_\_)) . '/api');

Answer (score 0):

**3 things:**

1. Check pluralize. Ex: "v1/post" should be "v1/posts"
2. Add "action" prefixe. Ex: "actionImport()"
3. Kebab format. Ex: "v1/getSample" should be "v1/get-sample"
4. Add rule 'extraPatterns' in main.php:urlManager if need be. Ex:

   ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'v1/report', 'extraPatterns'=>['analytics' => 'analytics',
                                                                                                    'report'    => 'report']],