# yii2: ActiveController name in url

Tags: php, yii2

For using ActiveController url has view, `http://localhost/index.php/controller_name`

How to make url without index.php - `http://localhost/controller_name`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable clean URL in Yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

In config/main.php

```
        'urlManager'       => [
            'showScriptName'               => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
...
]
```