# Yii2 url parameters with slash

Tags: yii2, url-routing, yii2-basic-app, yii-url-manager

I'm new in Yii2 framework and I didn't understand how rules in urlManager work.

I have my url `controller/action?id=1` and I want `controller/action/id/` or `controller/action/1`. How can I do that with url management ?

Thanks !

Comment: see this http://blog.neattutorials.com/seo-friendly-urls-in-yii2/, OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2

Comment: I think, it is necessary to clarify, that you're talking about ALL parameters (including those of it, that can be non-described in url rule). Because the only way that I know - to describe it in url rule or create custom UrlRule Class, implementing createUrl() method

Answer (score 1):

If your argument is number then use this rule:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

If your argument is text then use this rule:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<name:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in rules array.
This is example
`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>'`

Then in your controller you will get id like this

`public function actionTest($id) {}`