# How to change base URL http://Domain/ProjectName/web/index.php to http://Domain/ProjectName in yii2

Tags: php, apache, http, yii2

How to change base url : http://Domain/ProjectName/web/index.php  to http://Domain/ProjectName  in Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable pretty url  in app/config/main.php (in advanced template) of /web.php in basic template

```
 $config = [
    //...
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        ],
        //...
```

for apache add this to your ProjectName/web/.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ProjectName/ 
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

see this for more [Enable clean URL in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have following directory structure:

```
/root
|
|--/logs // or any other folder
|--/html <-- this is where DOMAIN.com is pointing
   |
   |--/ProjectName
      |
      |--/assets
      |--/web
      |--// and other folder
```

what you can do is move your project folder outside of the `html`. then copy only the `web` folder of your app inside your `html` folder and rename it to `ProjectName` (or any other). now your folder structure should look something like this:

```
/root
|
|--/logs // or any other folder
|--/html <-- this is where DOMAIN.com is pointing
   |
   |--/ProjectName
      |
      |--/assets
      |--/css
      |--/index.php <-- EDIT this one
      |--// and other files you had in web folder
|--/ProjectName
   |
   |--/assets
   |--/web
   |--// and other folder
```

finally open the `index.php` (file pointed above) and replace following lines:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');
```

with this:

```
$project_path = __DIR__ . '/../../PojectName';

require($project_path . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require($project_path . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require($project_path . '/config/web.php');
```

that's it. now you can access your application at: `http://DOMAIN/ProjectName`

hope that helps. if not let me know in the comment.