# How to prevent Yii2 redirecting to localhost after ajax call instead of calling controller method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, http-status-code-302

Operating within the Yii2 framework I have html form buttons that will toggle a certain feature. Using JS I intercept the submit action and execute an ajax post to `r?=reports/sales` that should, in theory, call the `actionSales` method in my `ReportsController`. However, this is not the case.

What is happening instead is the ajax call returns an error with status `302` and subsequently redirects me to `localhost`.

I have been searching the net for answers to this and I've come up with nothing but more questions.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could lead me in the right direction to a possible solution or a better understanding of why this is happening.

I have also included the response headers received in the ajax error callback.

**snippet of sales.php view where my Yii2 generated html form buttons are located**

```
 <div class="block-options pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-default dropdown-toggle enable-tooltip" data-toggle="dropdown" title="" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: -15px;" data-original-title="Options" aria-expanded="false"><span class="btn-ripple animate" style="height: 34px; width: 34px; top: -2px; left: -0.953125px;"></span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <?php
                    if ($showGrid) {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <?= Html::beginForm(['reports/sales'], 'post', ['class' => 'sale-grid-view-choice']); ?>
                            <?= Html::submitButton('Show Graph <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o pull-right"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-square btn-default clearBtn', 'name' => 'showGrid']) ?>
                            <?= Html::hiddenInput('showGrid', 'false',['class'=>'show-grid-value']); ?>
                            <?= Html::endForm() ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <?= Html::beginForm(['reports/sales'], 'post', ['class' => 'sale-grid-view-choice']); ?>
                            <?= Html::submitButton('Show Table <i class="fa fa-table pull-right"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-square btn-default clearBtn', 'name' => 'hideGrid']) ?>
                            <?= Html::hiddenInput('showGrid', 'true',['class'=>'show-grid-value']); ?>
                            <?= Html::endForm() ?>

                        </li>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li>
                        <?= Html::beginForm(['reports/sales'], 'post', ['class' => 'sale-grid-view-choice']); ?>
                        <?= Html::submitButton('Reset <i class="fa fa-mail-reply fa-fw pull-right"></i>', ['class' => 'btn btn-square btn-default clearBtn', 'name' => 'hideGrid']) ?>
                        <?= Html::hiddenInput('showGrid', 'false',['class'=>'show-grid-value']); ?>
                        <?= Html::endForm() ?>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript code executing ajax call**

```
$(document).on("submit", ".sale-grid-view-choice", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var showGrid = $(this).find(".show-grid-value").val() == "true" ? true : false;

  if (showGrid) {
    $("#widget-chart-classic").hide();
    $("#widget-grid-classic").removeClass("hide");

  } else {
    $("#widget-chart-classic").show();
    $("#widget-grid-classic").hide();
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    data: {
      "showGrid": showGrid
    },
    url: "r?=reports/sales",
    success: function(sessionVariable) {
      console.log("Successfully updated grid view session variable to", sessionVariable);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log("Ajax call to update grid view session variable could not be processed", e);
    }
  });
})
```

**Output from calling `e.getAllResponseHeaders()` in ajax's `error: function(e){}` callback**

```
 "Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sat, 25 Mar 2017 20:24:00 GMT
X-Debug-Duration: 136
X-Redirect: http://localhost/
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.1
X-Debug-Link: /debug/default/view?tag=58d6d1e08e8c8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Debug-Tag: 58d6d1e08e8c8
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Content-Length: 0
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.1 mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
"
```

**UPDATE**

After changing my URL from `r?=reports/sales` to `?r=reports/sales`, as well as having tried `Url::to("/reports/sales")` method as suggested, I got exactly the same result as before: the ajax returns a `302` status error with exactly the same output for the response headers as before.

Anything else I could be missing?

**UPDATE 2**

It seems I am now also being redirected to `localhost` after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your url, try changing `r?=reports/sales` by `?r=reports/sales`.

Even though, it would be better if you could generate the Url using Yii's helper `Url::to('/reports/sales')`

Comment: I have changed the URL to `?r=reports/sales` and I have also tried using `Url::to(["reports/sales"])` but both lead to the same result.

Comment: So you have in your js code this: `url: "<?=Url::to('/reports/sales')?>",` and it does not work?

Comment: I tried `Url::to('/reports/sales')` as well as `Url::to(["reports/sales"])`. Both of them return `"/reports/sales"` in the DOM.

Comment: Do you have the [pretty urls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls) enabled?

Comment: It seems so: ``` 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ]```

Comment: But does it work? I mean, you can call your app with pretty urls? not like index.php?r=controller/action, but /controller/action

Comment: Unfortunately not. It does not call the controller.

Comment: Then you have to configure your web server and .htaccess. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525320/enable-clean-url-in-yii2).