# roxymce file manager using in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-modules

I am a newbie in yii2. I want to use `roxymce` file manager in my `yii2` project. I followed [these docs](https://github.com/navatech/yii2-roxymce) for use in `yii` but when using [this section](https://github.com/navatech/yii2-roxymce/blob/master/docs/without.md), I get `Undefined variable: form` error and when use `ActiveForm::begin()` in I get `Getting unknown property: navatech\roxymce\models\UploadForm::thumb` error. I want to know when I must use that's controllers in my project. This code for my `fileupload` view:

```
<?php

use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\helpers\Url;


$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Upload Course Files');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Presented Courses'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'], 'action' => '#']); ?>
    <?php $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(['id' => 'fieldID1'])->label(false) ?>
    <a href="<?=Url::to([
        '/roxymce/default',
        'type' => 'media',
        'input' => 'fieldID1',
        'dialog' => 'iframe',
    ]) ?>" id="fileup" class="fancybox" ><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
    <?php ActiveForm::end();?>


<?php
$this->registerJsFile('@web/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
$this->registerCssFile('@web/css/jquery.fancybox.min.css', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
$this->registerJs(' 
$("#fileup").fancybox({  type: "iframe"});  
', View::POS_END);
?>
```

And this code is for the controller of this view(`fileupload`):

```
public function actionUploadfile()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();
    return $this->render('uploadfile',['model'=>$model]);
}
```

And this my main config file in backend directory:

```
'modules' => [

        'roxymce' => [
            'class' => 'navatech\roxymce\Module',
            'uploadFolder' => '@app/web/uploads/images',
            'uploadUrl' => '/uploads/images',
        ],

    ],
```

I used yii2 advancd template. If anyone used this module, please hint me.

Comment: add your code. What you tried so far?

Comment: Do not use links to code in your questions. Add code directly instead.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I added my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply becouse the variable `$form` is not defined if you use the code like int the example. In your view when you use the extension you need to use `ActiveForm::begin()` like this:

**Simple example**

```
<?php 

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'roxymce-form']); 

echo $form->field($model, 'thumb')->textInput(['id' => 'fieldID'])->label(false); 

?>

<a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to([
    '/roxymce/default',
    'type'   => 'image',
    'input'  => 'fieldID',
    'dialog' => 'fancybox',
]) ?>"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>

<script>
    $("a").fancybox();
</script>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

**[Edit]**

It was pretty hard to run it but in the end I succeeded. I use basic template of Yii2.
Start with install package with `composer` like in the guide. After this create the classes of assets bundles to publish javascript packages. My assets bundles are these and they are locate in `applicationroot/assets` folder:

*assets/AppAsset.php*

```
<?php 
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
    public $jsOptions = [
        'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD,
    ];
}
```

*assets/FancyBoxAsset.php*

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class FancyBoxAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/fancybox/source';

    public $js = [
        'jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
    ];
}
```

*assets/FontAwesomeAsset.php*

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class FontAwesomeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/fontawesome';
    public $css = [
        'css/font-awesome.min.css',
    ];
}
```

*assets/LazyLoadAsset.php*

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class LazyLoadAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/jquery.lazyload';
}
```

*assets/PatternflyTreeviewAsset.php*

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class PatternflyTreeviewAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/patternfly-bootstrap-treeview/dist';
    public $css = [
        'bootstrap-treeview.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'bootstrap-treeview.js',
    ];
}
```

*assets/TinymceAsset.php*

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class TinymceAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@bower/tinymce';
    public $jsOptions = [
        'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD,
    ];
}
```

Now you must to add in your config file this lines of code:

*config/web.php*

```
return [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    ...
    'modules' => [
        'roxymce' => [
            'class' => 'navatech\roxymce\Module',
            'uploadFolder' => '@app/web/uploads/images',
            'uploadUrl' => '../uploads/images',
        ],
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '' => 'site/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ]
    ...
];
```

After you need to configure your application for work in a clean URL context. Follow this for more information about:  [Enable clean URL in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47328738/5789458)

Now you can finally fully use the plugin in all its contexts. There are two methods for use it:

1. **Integrated with TinyMce**

*views/site/tinymceIntegrated.php*

```
<?php
use \app\assets;

assets\FontAwesomeAsset::register($this);
assets\LazyLoadAsset::register($this);
assets\FancyBoxAsset::register($this);
assets\PatternflyTreeviewAsset::register($this);
assets\TinymceAsset::register($this);

// Include ActiveRecord Model
echo \navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget::widget([
    'model'     => app\models\YourModel::findOne(1),
    'attribute' => 'content',
]);

// Sample HTML without ActiveRecord Model
echo \navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget::widget([
    'name' => 'Post[content]',
]);
```

2. **Without TinyMce**

*views/site/tinymceWithout.php*

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use \app\assets;

assets\FontAwesomeAsset::register($this);
assets\LazyLoadAsset::register($this);
assets\FancyBoxAsset::register($this);
assets\PatternflyTreeviewAsset::register($this);
//assets\TinymceAsset::register($this);

$js = <<<JS
    $("a").fancybox();
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY, 'upload-handler');
?>       
<a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to([
    '/roxymce/default',
    'type' => 'image',
    'dialog' => 'fancybox',
]) ?>"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
```

With this configuration for me work.

Comment: This not works, Now I edit the question. I get this error when use your solution: 'Getting unknown property: navatech\roxymce\models\UploadForm::thumb'

Comment: If you use ActiveForm with Model you need to add property "thumb" to UploadForm Class .

Comment: I want to use https://github.com/navatech/yii2-roxymce/blob/master/docs/without.md in my project witout active form

Comment: In example the widget work with ActiveForm component so you must use it

Comment: if I use it I get an input box in view and when I want to upload file Module alert 'something is wrong' and files don't upload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159969/discussion-between-alvarofvr-and-farshid).

Comment: I do that but not work(don't upload file) and I use advanced yii 2.